# Formatting a plot in Seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I made a PMF plot using seaborn:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

n= 1000 #number of trials
p= 0.5 #probability

trial_2 = np.random.binomial(n,p,1000)

sns.displot(trial_2, stat = 'probability') 
trial_2_mean= np.mean(trial_2)
plt.axvline(trial_2_mean,color='red') 
plt.xlabel("Number of Successes")
red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='Mean')
plt.legend(handles=[red_patch])
```

I want to add text to the plot like below (the n=60 and p=0.1):
[image: ("C:\Users\Workstation\OneDrive\Pictures\pmf plot.png")]

Also how do I plot in a format similar to the one in the picture (straight lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do following:

```
from scipy.stats import binom
n = 50 
p = 0.1
x = [x for x in range(15)]

trial_2 = binom.pmf(x, n, p)
sns.scatterplot(x, trial_2,label=('$n=50, p=0.1$'))
plt.vlines(x, 0, trial_2, colors='red', lw=3, alpha=0.4)
plt.xticks(x)
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.xlabel('Number of Successes')
plt.show()
```

Produces:

[image]